# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner with declarative and annotated beans

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a declarative spring config

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
   @Bean 
   public someBean() {
      return new Bean1();
   }
}
```

and a @Component annotated Bean

```
@Component
public class Bean2 {   
}
```

Now I would like to use both of then in my UnitTest

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public void UnitTest {
   @Autowired Bean1 bean1;

   @Autowired Bean2 bean2;
}
```

but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public void UnitTest {
   @Autowired Bean1 bean1;

   @Autowired Bean2 bean2;
}
```

For class Bean2, you can add the @ComponentScan annotation:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com....package.of.bean2")
public class SpringConfig {
   @Bean 
   public someBean() {
      return new Bean1();
   }
}
```

If you don't want to add the ComponentScan to your SpringConfig class, you can add an additional test config class with the ComponentScan annotation and add it to the ContextConfiguration annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringConfig.class, SpringTestConfig.class})
```